# Access pom elements from another file

Tags: javascript, angular, automation, protractor, pageobjects

I want to define my web elements into a separate js file from my test file (i'm using protractor).

I have defined my pom.js object:

```
    let web_elements = function() {

    this.get_login_mail,
        function() {
            return element(by.id('email'));
        }
}
```

And called it in my test file like this:

```
  web_elements.get_login_mail().sendKeys('dasdad);
```

But when i run it i get a **"Failed: web_elements is not defined"** error and I don't understand why. My js knowledge is very low.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that i've included the file :

```
const myModule = require('./pom');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is "_pom elements_" here?

Comment: page object model, i've tried to define the elements in a seperate file then call them every time i need them in my test file, if that was your question, if not pls add more information

Comment: what does `console.log(myModule)` returns?

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't defined what `web_elements` is hence the error message. You can access it from `myModule`.

```
myModule.webElements
```

Second, you defined `web_elements` as a function. So you should call it as a function also.

```
myModule.web_elements()
```

Finally you have

```
myModule.webElements().sendKeys('dasdad');
```